# Solving the equation $ \frac{B \tanh \left(C \sqrt{G_{12}}\right)}{\sqrt{G_{12}}}=k $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I would like to know if it's possible to solve the following equation for $G_{12}$:
$$
\frac{B \tanh \left(C \sqrt{G_{12}}\right)}{\sqrt{G_{12}}}=k
$$
where $B$, $k$, and $C$ are real constants greater than 0. I'm fairly sure it's unsolvable but there might be a method that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: that's not even an equation; it's an expression.

Comment: If you want to solve an equation, you need the other side.  Otherwise you might want to simplify an expression, but I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Forgot to add the other side, done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the problem simpler, let $C \sqrt {G_{12}}=x$ and $a= \frac k{B\, C}$ to face the equation
$$ \tanh(x)=a x$$ Beside the trivial solution $x=0$, there will be a root if $a<1$.

If $x$ is not too large, we could use the simple Padé approximant
$$\tanh(x)\sim\frac{x \left(x^2+15\right)}{6 x^2+15}$$ which is more than acceptable up to $x=2$ and we are left with a quadratic equation the solution of which being
$$x_{(1)}=\sqrt{\frac{15 (1-a)}{6 a-1}}\qquad \text{if} \qquad a > \frac 16$$ Much better would be
$$\tanh(x)\sim\frac{x \left(x^4+105 x^2+945\right)}{15 \left(x^4+28 x^2+63\right)}$$ which would left us with a quartic equation
$$(1-15 a) x^4+(105-420 a) x^2-945 (a-1)=0$$ giving
$$x_{(2)}=\sqrt{ \frac{3 \left(\sqrt{35} \sqrt{380 a^2-88 a+23}-140 a+35\right)}{2 (15 a-1)}  }\qquad \text{if} \qquad a > \frac 1{15}$$

These are simple but we can continue with a still better approximation
$$\tanh(x)\sim \frac{x \left(x^6+378 x^4+17325 x^2+135135\right)}{7 \left(4 x^6+450 x^4+8910 x^2+19305\right)}$$
$$(1-28 a) x^6+(378-3150 a) x^4-3465 (18 a-5) x^2-135135 (a-1)=0$$ which is cubic in $x^2$ and it can be solved. The nasty result would write (assuming $a >\frac 1 {28}$)
$$x_{(3)}^2=\frac{2}{28 a-1}\left(63-525 a +\sqrt{21(24780 a^2-3910 a+481 ) }\cos \left(\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}(\theta )\right)\right)$$ where
$$\theta=\frac{3\sqrt 3 } {2\sqrt 7 }\frac {-3108560 a^3+804860 a^2-108725 a+10333 } {\left(24780 a^2-3910 a+481\right)^{3/2} }$$

Now, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a & x_{(1)}& x_{(1)}& x_{(3)} & \text{exact} \\
 0.95 & 0.39947 & 0.39946 & 0.39946 &  0.39946 \\
 0.90 & 0.58387 & 0.58381 & 0.58381 &  0.58381 \\
 0.85 & 0.74080 & 0.74059 & 0.74059 &  0.74059 \\
 0.80 & 0.88852 & 0.88802 & 0.88802 &  0.88802 \\
 0.75 & 1.03510 & 1.03402 & 1.03402 &  1.03402 \\
 0.70 & 1.18585 & 1.18376 & 1.18376 &  1.18376 \\
 0.65 & 1.34549 & 1.34164 & 1.34164 &  1.34164 \\
 0.60 & 1.51911 & 1.51223 & 1.51222 &  1.51222 \\
 0.55 & 1.71312 & 1.70098 & 1.70096 &  1.70096 \\
 0.50 & 1.93649 & 1.91504 & 1.91501 &  1.91501 \\
 0.45 & 2.20294 & 2.16449 & 2.16439 &  2.16439 \\
 0.40 & 2.53546 & 2.46434 & 2.46406 &  2.46406 \\
 0.35 & 2.97719 & 2.83843 & 2.83761 &  2.83761 \\
 0.30 & 3.62284 & 3.32735 & 3.32472 &  3.32471 \\
 0.25 & 4.74342 & 4.00673 & 3.99736 &  3.99730 \\
 0.20 & 7.74597 & 5.03871 & 5.00005 &  4.99955 \\
 0.15 &   n/a   & 6.87104 & 6.67232 &  6.66665 \\
 0.10 &   n/a   & 11.7601 & 10.0962 &  10.0000
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, if you want to polist the solution, use Newton method which will give the iterates
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{\sinh (2 x)-2 x}{a (1+\cosh (2 x))-2}$$ Suppose $a=\frac 14$ and use $x_0=\sqrt{\frac{45}{2}}$ given by the worst (this is $x_{(1)}$). Yo would get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 4.7434164902525689980 \\
 1 & 3.9984894607342270581 \\
 2 & 3.9973026996796417165 \\
 3 & 3.9973026920604329747 \\
 4 & 3.9973026920604329744
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you need to work with small values of $a$, corresponding to large values of $x$, you could use
$$\tanh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}=\frac{2}{1+e^{-2x}}-1 \sim 1-2e^{-2x}$$ and solve, for a good pproximation
$$1-2e^{-2x}=a x\implies x=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{2} W\left(-\frac{4 }{a}e^{-2/a}\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. Since, in such a case, the argument is quite small, a good approximation would then be 
$$x=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{2}{a e^{2/a}-4}$$ For $a=0.25$, this would give
$$x=\frac{4 \left(e^8-18\right)}{e^8-16}\approx 3.99730$$ and for $a=0.15$
$$x=\frac{20 \left(3 e^{40/3}-86\right)}{9 e^{40/3}-240}\approx 6.66665$$